# `cmp -b file1 file2` responses: "file1 file2 differ: 12 byte, line 2 is 154 l 151 i", what is '154' and '151' in reference to?

Tags: file-comparison

```
$ cmp -b file1 file2 
file1 file2 differ: 12 byte, line 2 is 154 l 151 i
```

in this response what do '154' and '151' refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GNU version of `cmp` (which you are using) prints the differing bytes when given the `-b` option.  If no printable representation of the byte can be shown, `cmp` will display

> [...] control bytes as a `^` followed by a letter of the alphabet and precede bytes that have the high bit set with `M-` (which stands for "meta").

(quote from the `cmp` manual on a GNU system).

154 in the output refers to the letter `l`, and 151 refers to the letter `i` (also visible in the output).  These are octal ASCII codes (see `man ascii`) for the first bytes in each file that differs between the files.